# Can I adjust the vertical position of checkboxes in HTML text?

Tags: html, css, checkbox, bootstrap-4, baseline

I'm creating a website with Bootstrap 4, and at least in Chrome on Windows 10, the checkboxes are shown a bit too high in a line:

[image]

These are `<input type="checkbox">` elements enclosed in `<label>`s.

I would like to move the checkbox itself down by 3px or so. Is this possible with CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `vertical-align: middle;`

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
    text <input type="checkbox" name="">
</div>
```

Comment: Nice, actually `-2px` is the most beautiful option across all browsers. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Using a flexbox is an option.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="container">
      <label for="checkbox1">Checkbox 1</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1">
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <label for="checkbox2">Checkbox 2</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2">
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <label for="checkbox3">Checkbox 3</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox3">
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <label for="checkbox4">Checkbox 4</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox4">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="container">
      <label for="checkbox5">Checkbox 5</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox5">
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <label for="checkbox6">Checkbox 6</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox6">
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <label for="checkbox7">Checkbox 7</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox7">
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <label for="checkbox8">Checkbox 8</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox8">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need multiple checkboxes in one line, which seems hard to do with a flexbox if I don't want to assign all checkboxes to `div`s manually.

Comment: I've adjusted the code to demonstrate multiple checkboxes on a line. Not too complicated.